# Length is returning undefined but value is showing

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, html-input

I have a function where I get an error saying "length" is null, I then did an alert to see the value and length and I see that the value is coming back in the loop, sometimes it has a String value and sometimes it has a number (eg. SUIT and then 8), but for some reason the length is showing as undefined?  The radioobj variable takes radio button values that are coming in from the form input.

```
function getRadioValue(radioobj) {
    radiovalue = "";
    for (i=0, n=radioobj.length; i<n; i++) {

        if (radioobj[i].checked) {
            radiovalue = radioobj[i].value;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!radiovalue) { return 0; }
    else { return radiovalue; }
}
```

Comment: 8 is a number and therefore doesn't have a length method.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? and on which var you get undefined for the length?

Comment: actually this is an existing piece of code which I am looking into.  I see that radioobj.length seems to be undefined for every single item.  So even if the value (radioobj.value) is "SUIT" or is a number like 8, the error message still says it is null or undefined when I try to return the output on the screen.

Comment: What is getting passed in for `radioobj`?  A DOM reference to an individual radio button?

Comment: Actually . . . it looks like it's expecting a collection of radio buttons . . . like all of the radio buttons in and individual radio group.  Is that what is getting passed to it?

Answer (score 0):

The way the code is written, it appears to be looking to take in a group of radio buttons and looping through them to find the one that is checked.  To do that, the input **MUST** be a collection of radio buttons . . . passing an individual reference to a radio button will not work (and will give an `undefined` value for `radioobj.length`).  Example:

**HTML**

```
<fieldset id="radioVals">
    <input type="radio" name="radioVals" id="val0" value="">Pick an value . . .</input>
    <input type="radio" name="radioVals" id="val1" value="Value1">Value 1</input>
    <input type="radio" name="radioVals" id="val2" value="Value1">Value 2</input>
</fieldset>
```

Given this group, if you were to pass in a reference to any of the individual radio buttons (e.g., using `document.getElementById`), you will get and error, because what is returned by that method is the reference to an individual element.

```
var radioOption = document.getElementById("val0");
window.console.log(radioOption.length);     // will log "undefined"
```

However, if you pass in an array of radio button elements (e.g., using `.children`), you can use the `for` loop, because the array will have a length.

```
var radioOptions = document.getElementById("radioVals").children;
window.console.log(radioOptions.length);     // will log "3"
```

From what you are describing, it sounds like the code is using the first approach, rather than the second.  There are certainly ways of doing this check with individual radio buttons, but that is not how this code has been set up.

Answer (score 0):

You can get collection of radios with the same id easily.
Use for it `document.forms['form_id']['radio_id']`:

```
<form id="form_id">
    <input type="radio" name="radio_name" id="radio_id" value="Value1" />Value 1
    <input type="radio" name="radio_name" id="radio_id" value="Value2" />Value 2
    <input type="radio" name="radio_name" id="radio_id" value="Value3" />Value 3
</form>

var radio_list = document.forms['form_id']['radio_id'];
alert(radio_list.lengh) // will "3"
```